# What is the correct way to embed license information into a Jupyter Notebook file?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I want to publish a Jupyter Notebook under Apache 2.0 license and therefore need to add a license header to the file, as instructed in the Apache 2.0 License file:

> APPENDIX: How to apply the Apache License to your work.
>
> To apply the Apache License to your work, attach the following
>      boilerplate notice, with the fields enclosed by brackets "[]"
>      replaced with your own identifying information. (Don't include
>      the brackets!)  The text should be enclosed in the appropriate
>      comment syntax for the file format. We also recommend that a
>      file or class name and description of purpose be included on the
>      same "printed page" as the copyright notice for easier
>      identification within third-party archives.
>
> Copyright [yyyy] [name of copyright owner]
>
> Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
>   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
>   You may obtain a copy of the License at
>
> http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
>
> Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
>   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
>   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or
>   implied.    See the License for the specific language governing
>   permissions and    limitations under the License.

However, just adding the header as JavaScript comment will make the notebook invalid:

```
//
// Copyright ...
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.
//

{
 "cells": [...],
 "metadata": {...},
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 4
}
```

or

```
/*
 * Copyright ...
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

{
 "cells": [...],
 "metadata": {...},
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 4
}
```

Both will not be loaded by JupiterLab.

I also noted that there is a top-level key `metadata` that should be the right place to add license information. However, the [documentation](https://nbformat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format_description.html#metadata) does not define a key to add license information.

What is the correct way to embed license information into a Jupyter Notebook file?

Answer (score 1):

Some solutions:

## 1. Repository License File

An [article](https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pcbi.1007007) recommends to  just add license information to the contained repository. This is easy to apply, but does not fulfill the guideline. (This is the wrong place to discuses the legal aspects.)

## 2. License Notice as Content

One could add a markdown cell into the notebook with the license information. This is also easy to apply, but does not support automated processing by e.g. search engines.

## 3. License as Custom Metadata Field

The current [notebook format definition (v4.4)](https://github.com/jupyter/nbformat/blob/master/nbformat/v4/nbformat.v4.4.schema.json) only defines the keys `authors`, `title`, `language_info`, `kernelspec`, and `orig_nbformat` in `metadata` , but also allows additional keys. So one could just add e.g. a `license` key. In a (declined) feature request, the [use of JSON-LD and schema.org](https://github.com/jupyter/nbformat/pull/46#issuecomment-245831564) was proposed to declare the license and other metadata. An adapted solution:

```
{
 "cells": [...],
 "metadata": {
  "@context": {
   "CreativeWork": "http://schema.org/CreativeWork",
   "Organization": "http://schema.org/Organization",
   "Person": "http://schema.org/Person",
   "author": "http://schema.org/author",
   "copyrightHolder": "http://schema.org/copyrightHolder",
   "copyrightYear": "http://schema.org/copyrightYear",
   "license": "http://schema.org/license",
   "name": "http://schema.org/name",
   "title": "http://schema.org/name",
   "url": "http://schema.org/url"
  },
  "@type": "CreativeWork",
  "author": [
   {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "<full author name>",
    "@id": "<some identifier URI, e.g. an ORCID URI>",
    "url": "<person website URL>"
   }
  ],
  "copyrightHolder": [
   {
    "@type": "Organization",
    "name": "<full organization name>",
    "url": "<organization website URL>"
   },
   {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "<full author name>",
    "@id": "<some identifier URI, e.g. an ORCID URI>",
    "url": "<person website URL>"
   }
  ],
  "copyrightYear": <year as yyyy>,
  "kernelspec": {...},
  "language_info": {...},
  "license": "<license URL>",
  "title": "<title of the notebook>"
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 4
}
```

Unfortunately, no additional keys are permitted in the root-node of jupyter notebooks and unknown keys will be removed by JupiterLab. Therefore, the `@context` and `@type` (`CreativeWork`) need to be added into the metadata node, which is not 100% correct, as the whole document (i.e. the root node) is the licensed `CreativeWork`. One could test it with e.g. Googles [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool). Applying this is a bit more work, but I think, it fulfills the guideline and it supports automated processing by e.g. search engines.